# Intercept WCF calls at the TCP level

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, network-programming

I've currently got a GUI program that connects to a server side application using WCF and the `net.tcp` binding. The interface used for the connection has a `CallbackContract` defined.

We're planning to move the server side processes to a new data center that won't be accessible from the client side, so the WCF calls will no longer work. However, our existing servers are able to connect to the data center, so we currently run the GUIs on these servers, and remote desktop onto the server.

However, this practice isn't scalable, so I've written a "man in the middle proxy" that runs on the server and listens for TCP connections. Our client applications connect to this, and it makes a connection to the WCF server in the data center. Everything sent to the proxy is forwarded to the WCF server application, and everything read from the WCF server application is sent to the GUI app. For all our non-WCF applications this works without a problem, but it refuses to work for any WCF application. I get the connection, and there's a brief exchange of data, but then everything stop.s

It seems like the `net.tcp` layer has detected there is a man in the middle and decided to stop sending/receiving data. I'm not using and security (the binding uses `SecurityMode.None`). I've also tried using the `portproxy` feature in the `netsh` command line application but get the same problem - every non WCF application works, but WCF applications don't!

I appreciate that this is a rather niche thing to be doing, but I was wondering if anyone had any insight into why I can't intercept the WCF traffic?

Comment: It's not `net.tcp` that detects anything. WCF validates the certificate of the remote server. In any case you can configure detailed tracing for any WCF service and even raw System.Net calls. Check the [WCF Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/index) section in the documentation. System.Net tracing is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing).

Comment: Finally, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915129/wcf-net-tcp-transport-security-how-to-disable-server-certificate-validation-on) shows how to disable certificate validation